# RuntimeException by using Google Youtube Api v3 in my android app

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the list of videos from Youtube channel.

You will see below the class to connect to Youtube and my Activity that interacts with this class. I get an exception "**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity VideoListActivity**" when calling **YouTube.Search.List.execute()**;

I am new in android, so I think there is a stupid mistake. Please help to **find it**, or maybe **suggest the another way** to get data from Youtube.

YoutubeConnector class

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class YoutubeConnector {
    private static YouTube youtube;
    private static YouTube.Search.List query;
    public static final String KEY = DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY;

    public static List<VideoItem> search() throws IOException {

        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName(R.string.app_name).build();

        query = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
        query.setKey(KEY);
        query.setType("video");
        query.setChannelId("**************");
        query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");

        SearchListResponse response = query.execute();
        List<SearchResult> results = response.getItems();
        List<VideoItem> items = new ArrayList<VideoItem>();

        for (SearchResult result : results) {
            VideoItem item = new VideoItem();
            item.setTitle(result.getSnippet().getTitle());
            item.setDescription(result.getSnippet().getDescription());
            item.setThumbnailURL(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl());
            item.setId(result.getId().getVideoId());
            items.add(item);
        }

        return items;

    }
}
```

VideoListActivity class

```
public class VideoListActivity extends ListActivity{

    List<VideoItem> videoFileList;

    public class VideoAapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    //.....................
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            videoFileList = YoutubeConnector.search();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setListAdapter(new VideoAapter(VideoListActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_video, videoFileList));
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
06-16 18:14:56.926 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.example.alex.youtubecanal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.example.alex.youtubecanal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex) with checksum 0x7eb43558 in OatFile /data/data/com.example.alex.youtubecanal/cache/slice-slice_5-classes.dex
06-16 18:14:57.631 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-16 18:14:57.631 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
06-16 18:14:57.631 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-1-786658172: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
06-16 18:14:57.631 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-1-786658172: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is false
06-16 18:14:57.636 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-16 18:14:57.636 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
06-16 18:14:57.636 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-16 18:14:57.641 30817-30817/com.example.alex.youtubecanal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.alex.youtubecanal, PID: 30817
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alex.youtubecanal/com.example.alex.youtubecanal.VideoListActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                                   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                                   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:245)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:128)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:370)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:298)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:110)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
                                                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                                                                                   at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
                                                                                   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
                                                                                   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
                                                                                   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
                                                                                   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
                                                                                   at com.example.alex.youtubecanal.YoutubeConnector.search(YoutubeConnector.java:37)
                                                                                   at com.example.alex.youtubecanal.VideoListActivity.onCreate(VideoListActivity.java:58)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the `YoutubeConnector.search` outside of `onCreate()` in an Async Thread. This basically means that the method is stalling the program and will cause the program to crash or hang. To fix, create a new class called Search for example:

SearchClass.java:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Search extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            videoFileList = YoutubeConnector.search();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String a){
        VideoListActivity.context.updateAdapter();
    }
}
```

VideoListActivity.java:

```
public class VideoListActivity extends ListActivity{

    static List<VideoItem> videoFileList;
    static Context context;
    public class VideoAapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    //.....................
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Search search= new Search();
        search.execute(new String[]{});


    }
    public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<String> list) {
        setListAdapter(new VideoAapter(VideoListActivity.this,R.layout.list_item_video, videoFileList));
     }
}
```

Hopefully this will work :). If it does not, just post the error, and we'll get back. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is coming from a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception). Hope it helps!